# Average for some selected record SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
ID     myDate       myTime     Value
1      2014-06-01   00:00:00   100
2      2014-06-01   01:00:00   125
3      2014-06-01   02:00:00   132
4      2014-06-01   03:00:00   139
5      2014-06-01   04:00:00   145
6      2014-06-01   05:00:00   148
FF.
24     2014-06-01   23:00:00   205
25     2014-06-02   00:00:00   209
26     2014-06-02   01:00:00   215
27     2014-06-02   02:00:00   223
FF.
48     2014-06-02   23:00:00   280
49     2014-06-03   00:00:00   290
50     2014-06-03   01:00:00   302
FF.
71     2014-06-03   22:00:00   389
72     2014-06-03   23:00:00   400
73     2014-06-04   00:00:00   405
FF.
```

I want to `Average` all the record from time 01:00:00 to 00:00:00 on the next day. For example:

I want to know the average value on '2014-06-01'. Then the average is value from 2014-06-01 01:00:00 until 2014-06-02 00:00:00.

How can I do this with SQL select statement?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a simple GROUP BY - have you tried that?

Comment: @Skram, Group By which column?

Comment: That's what makes it difficult.  Because you want to cross the two days, you cannot do a simple group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started out by subtracting an hour from the dates to "fix" them to line up with days.  Add the date and time, then subtract an hour.

Then it was a simple group by.  This will work on MS SQL Server.

```
WITH CorrectedDates AS (
  SELECT 
  DateAdd(hh,-1,DateAdd(hh,DatePart(hh,myTime),myDate)) AS newDate, Value
  FROM table1
  )
SELECT CAST(newDate AS DATE) AS MainDate, AVG(Value)
FROM CorrectedDates cd
GROUP BY CAST(newDate AS DATE)
```

To get only a single date, simply add the following between the FROM and GROUP BY clauses:

```
WHERE NewDate = '2014-6-1'
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your syntax. But it seems that the result is incorrect. Like in the fiddle, the average for '2014-06-01' start from 01:00:00, is 200, 300, 300, 300, 300. So the result should be, 280.

Comment: Double check.  I set up the data to increment 100 at 0100 which is when you said to start the 24 hours of that day going to 0000 the next day.  If I did it incorrect adjust the fiddle so each day would come out divisible by 100 and post the link.

Comment: Hi KingOfAllTrades, I tried your syntax and give me an error. The error is, .Net SqlClient Data Provider, Error Message: Can't call methods on date. So?

Answer (score 0):

I have my own answer: Check on [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21393)

```
if (OBJECT_ID('[TempDB]..[#DataTable]') is not null)
    drop table #DataTable
create table #DataTable (
    [Date] date,
    [Time] time,
    Value int
)
declare @inputDate date
set @inputDate = '2014-6-1'

insert into #DataTable values
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '0:0', 100),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '1:0', 200),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '2:0', 300),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '3:0', 400),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '4:0', 500),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '5:0', 600),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '6:0', 700),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '7:0', 800),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '8:0', 900),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '9:0', 1000),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '10:0', 1100),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '11:0', 1200),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '12:0', 1300),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '13:0', 1400),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '14:0', 1500),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '15:0', 1600),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '16:0', 1700),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '17:0', 1800),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '18:0', 1900),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '19:0', 2000),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '20:0', 2100),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '21:0', 2200),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '22:0', 2300),
(cast('2014-6-1' as date), '23:0', 2400),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '0:0', 2500),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '1:0', 2600),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '2:0', 2700),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '3:0', 2800),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '4:0', 2900),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '5:0', 3000),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '6:0', 3100),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '7:0', 3200),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '8:0', 3300),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '9:0', 3400),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '10:0', 3500),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '11:0', 3600),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '12:0', 3700),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '13:0', 3800),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '14:0', 3900),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '15:0', 4000),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '16:0', 4100),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '17:0', 4200),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '18:0', 4300),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '19:0', 4400),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '20:0', 4500),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '21:0', 4600),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '22:0', 4700),
(cast('2014-6-2' as date), '23:0', 4800)

select @inputDate Tanggal, avg(d.Value) [Rata-rata]
from #DataTable d
where
    (d.[Date] = @inputDate and d.[Time] <> '0:0')
    or (d.[Date] = DATEADD(day, 1, @inputDate) and d.[Time] = '0:0')
```

Thank you.

Comment: If using fiddle you can select 'markdown output' from the drop down next to RUN SQl button and copy and paste the results into your answer, to get nicely formatted answer here.

Comment: And my query works on your data set with the same results.  [my query, your data on fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91ffc/1/0)

Comment: @KingOfAllTrades, Can you please modify with conditional statement? Let say, I just want to see the average on '2014-06-01'. I'll vote and mark your answer.